# nodejs re-encoding uploaded files for security reason.... but how?

Tags: node.js, security, file-upload

I'm using nodejs and developing file upload system on my personal project.

From one blog, (it's not english site so I won't link it here) I saw that I have to re-encoding fil. If not, high-level attacker can insert malicious shell code in normal file (he told jpeg as an example) even I limit the extension of uploaded files and change the original filename and hide the filepath.

My question is, so how to re-encoding files in nodejs??
there are several types of file and I don't know how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While doing a file upload, there are several hardening to increase security.

1. Rename the file name with extension
2. Use whitelist to check the file's extension.
3. Use whitelist to check the file's mime types.
4. Use whitelist to check the file's magic bytes.
5. Set content-type and no-sniff headers to response if you buffer (accessible) your files from HTTP

Re-encoding means in here actually is the fourth step in above.

Determine file type with reading magic bytes;

```
const FileType = require('file-type');
const readChunk = require('read-chunk');
(async () => {
 const buffer = readChunk.sync('Unicorn.png', 0, 4100);

 console.log(await FileType.fromBuffer(buffer));
 //=> {ext: 'png', mime: 'image/png'}
})();
```

There are several packages that you can decide to use:
https://github.com/sindresorhus/file-type

Comment: Thanks for your help! In fact, I have another question...
 Somebody told me that if the extension of file is text (txt) or other document type, it wouldn't be a problem because those extension only can open and read content, not execute some malicious code.
Is that a real??

Comment: yes, an attacker cannot execute code, in general, using text files (txt ext.) is not a problem. but you need to be sure you set "content-type" properly in your response header